# Raman Spectrum of Graphene

Tags: raman, carbon-family

I recently took a raman spectrum for a sample of graphene-pla. The result had the characteristic G and D bands associated with Graphene, but not the 2D. But there is a broad peak at around 3100, which goes up from 2600. The sample was treated before being characterized. Does anyone know why this might have happened?